# Auto-updating software; is FTP a good option?

Tags: c++, auto-update

I'd like to build in updating functionality to a desktop Windows/Mac application and I'm wondering if there is a 'right answer' how to implement this. For instance the client could use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to connect to an FTP server - there are many possible ways but hopefully people have already decided which is best.

Comment: FTP is problematic - not all firewalls let it through. HTTP is by far the most likely to be able to get through a firewall without issue.

Comment: If you software is large enough you could consider P2P updating to save you bandwidth.

Comment: @JoeMcGrath: then you risk having your updates blocked by corporate firewalls (assuming you use torrents, which would make sense otherwise), and maybe even banned by corporate IT departments.  If the software in question is something cool for home users, maybe, but otherwise P2P is probably not the best option (and besides, chances are the total amount of update data the OP is talking about is not Google-scale).

Comment: @JoeMcGrath - no this is strictly a client-server deal, for corporate type clients.

Comment: @MarcB - are there libraries that will make downloading files by HTTP as easy as FTP? Is performance as good? And what about security, how does that get handled?

Comment: @john: ftp was never designed to be a secure protocol. there's s/ftp, but it's even less widespread than ftp. Securing http with SSL is trivial. Any decent http library should have https support baked in from the get-go.

Comment: @MarcB that's not what I mean. I mean with FTP you have to supply a login as part of how FTP works. I don't understand how HTTP works - hence this question - I don't want to have to write a ton of code to download a file from a server.

Answer (score 0):

FTP can bring several advantages when used for automatically updating your software. The part that will fetch the new version from the FTP server, download it and run it instead of the old version is easy to implement and the main advantage is that it will not require any server side software.
The disadvantage using FTP is that there is no way to check the date/time stamp of the file before downloading it, like you can do while communicating with a server side software. That can be solved by placing a small file (.txt) where you store the new version information so the current version can check that file and see if it should download the full version.
The other side of an FTP auto update mechanism would be another software you need to create which will upload new versions, create the version details text file and maintain a log of uploads, versions and downloads.